# How to kill a process and all of its children in C when executing the process by execv()?

Tags: c, signals, child-process

I'm trying to implement a `timeout`-like command on a `unix`-based operating system as follows:

```
int                  pid;
timer_t              timer_id;
struct sigevent      timer_event;
struct itimerspec    timer_value;

void timeout_signal_handler(int sig_no)
{
    kill(pid, SIGKILL);
}

int create_timer()                        { /* implementation */ }
int start_timer_oneshot(int interval_ms)  { /* implementation */ }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int   status, pid_return;
    void  *signal_return;

    if (argc < 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    signal_return = signal(SIGUSR1, timeout_signal_handler);
    if (signal_return == SIG_ERR)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    create_timer();
    start_timer_oneshot(TIMEOUT);

    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        execv(argv[1], &argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
        status = -1;
        while (status == -1)
            status = wait(&pid_return);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

And I use this utility as follows:

```
./timeout example
```

The `example` program runs for a couple of seconds and forks a couple of processes. When the timer expires in `timeout`, only the parent process of `example` gets killed and its children keep printing on the console.

When I run the `example` without `timeout`, and press `Ctrl+C`, the parent and all its children get killed successfully.

Can anyone please let me know how could I fix this in my `timeout` program?

Comment: Sending the kill signal to a process will not do anything to the childs. You could use process groups to kill all childs. Try looking into `setsid`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. If I call `setsid` in the forked process before executing `execv`, then, how could I send a signal to the new process of group of forked process from the parent process when timer expires?

Comment: a 'pid' is a 'pid_t' as defined in:  #include <unistd.h>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to call `kill()` on pid `0`. This sends the signal to all members of the calling process' process group.

This however only works if the process, which had been `fork()`/`exec*()`'ed (or its children) does not change its (their) process group by itself.

From [`man 2 kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html):

> If  pid  is  0, sig shall be sent to all processes (excluding an unspecified set of system processes) whose process group ID is equal to the process group ID of the sender, and for which the process
>          has permission to send a signal.

Comment: Note that it also signals the timeout process.  It would be feasible for the child to make itself into a process group leader and then have the parent process signal that process group (via [`setpgid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setpgid.html)).  The parent knows which process group that is (it is the process group ID with the same number as the PID of the child), so it can send the signal to the negative of the child's PID to indicate a signal to the child's process group.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The problem is still that the `kill(0, SIGKILL);` will also kill the parent process of `timeout`, and I don't get returned from `status = wait(&pid_return);`

Comment: @moorara: *Jonathan Leffer* mentioned a solution to this in his comment above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738216/how-to-kill-a-process-and-all-of-its-children-in-c-when-executing-the-process-by/31738865#comment51413050_31738865). Btw, reading the documentation for the involved functions helps ...

Comment: Also note that even with Jonathan's solution, if any of the forked / exec'd processes calls `setpgid()` to create a new group or `setsid()` to create a new session it will not belong to the same group anymore and as such won't be killed.